# A question regarding independeance

Tags: probability

Sorry for this simple question, I'm a first year student, it's really basic but I don't know how to answer
The question is:
A random experiment is conducted which has sample space
$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\}$.
Assume that all elementary events are equally likely to occur.
Let the event $A = \{14,15,16,17,18,19,20 \}$.
Let $F$ be an event such $P(F)= 0.25$.
Explain why, for this experiment, $A$ and $F$ cannot be independent.

Comment: May be it should be $\mathbb{P}(F) = 0.75$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$ \frac{|A \cap F|}{20} = P(A \cap F)$$

If $A$ and $F$ were independent, then 
$$P(A \cap F) = P(A) P(F) = \frac{7}{80}$$
which implies $|A \cap F| = \frac{7}{4}$ which is absurd.